# Directory is valid in Intellij but NOT in CMD and .jar

Tags: java, cmd, jar, path

i have problem in this part of code. From folder, iam loading all images and then save it as part of object to list of these object.

When i run it in Intellij, everything is OK. I print isDirectory() just because of this problem. In intellij it returns true.

But when i try it to run in cmd through jar, than there is problem. Method isDirectory() returns false and listFiles() throws NullPointerException.

I also tried to save in String directory whole path manually, but nothing changed. In intellij it runs perfectly and its problem in CMD with jar. Problem is really in this. Jar worked perfectly before i started use these functions. Thank you for any ideas.

```
 private void loadAllExercises(){
        public String directory = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\pictures\\";
        File directory = new File(directory);

        System.out.println(directory.isDirectory());

        for (File file : directory.listFiles()) {
            loadExercise(file);
            }
        }

    private void loadExercise(File file){
        if(file.getName().toLowerCase().endsWith(".jpg")) {
            Exercise exercise = new Exercise(file.getName());
            this.allExercises.add(exercise);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

`System.getProperty("user.dir")` returns the current directory when the application was started and is probably not what you intended. If you want to point to your home directory because that's where your `pictures` directory is, try using `System.getProperty("user.home")`.

Comment: Thank you, i understand now, whats the problem. Problem ist that jar is in target. "user.home" is not good for me because my pictues are part of project folder. I tried this. I stayed with my code but after getProperty I also use replace("target",""). After that, it works with jar also. But I have another problem. I created exe from jar and its running from different location again. Now, best for me would be find way how to find location of my project folder somewhere in computer. I you will have any idea, it will also help. But than you for advice.

Comment: If you mean that you have pictures that are built into your jar/exe as static resources, then you could use `getResourceAsStream()` to read them. If you mean that the pictures are somewhere else, you could use a command line option to let the user specify the pictures path at runtime. Another option would be to set an environment variable with the path and have your app read that value. Or you put the path in a configuration file that your app can read when it starts up. Good luck!